# cURL, SSL and POST

Tags: post, ssl, curl

I connected to my account and get table source using cURL with post, now web are protected SSL. I modify script but when I try to sing in I just get:

`HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2011 10:13:12 GMT Server: Apache Set-Cookie: session=sessio_hide; expires=Thu, 09-Aug-2012 10:13:12 GMT Status: 302 Location: index.php Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html`

Can anybody help? :)

Answer (score 0):

just a noob in this...but based on the http status code 302 i'd suggest you make sure to set follow location true to go through redirections....just my two cents...hope it helps